# Dynamic Linq Groupby SELECT Key, List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Dynamic Linq helper for grouping data. My code is as follows :

```
Employee[] empList = new Employee[6];
empList[0] = new Employee() { Name = "CA", State = "A", Department = "xyz" };
empList[1] = new Employee() { Name = "ZP", State = "B", Department = "xyz" };
empList[2] = new Employee() { Name = "AC", State = "B", Department = "xyz" };
empList[3] = new Employee() { Name = "AA", State = "A", Department = "xyz" };
empList[4] = new Employee() { Name = "A2", State = "A", Department = "pqr" };
empList[5] = new Employee() { Name = "BA", State = "B", Department = "pqr" };

var empqueryable = empList.AsQueryable();
var dynamiclinqquery  = DynamicQueryable.GroupBy(empqueryable, "new (State, Department)", "it");
```

How can I get back the Key and corresponding list of grouped items i.e IEnumerable of {Key, List} from dynamiclinqquery ?

Comment: By DynamicQueryable are you referring to this class? http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/source/browse/branches/DbContext-Test/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Dynamic/DynamicQueryable.cs?r=2377&spec=svn2377

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem by defining a selector that projects the Key as well as Employees List.

```
       var eq = empqueryable.GroupBy("new (State, Department)", "it").Select("new(it.Key as Key, it as Employees)");
       var keyEmplist = (from dynamic dat in eq select dat).ToList();

       foreach (var group in keyEmplist)
       {
           var key = group.Key;
           var elist = group.Employees;

           foreach (var emp in elist)
           {

           }                                          
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GroupBy` method should still return something that implements `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`.

While you might not be able to actually *cast* it (I'm assuming it's `dynamic`), you can certainly still make calls on it, like so:

```
foreach (var group in dynamiclinqquery)
{
    // Print out the key.
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", group.Key);

    // Write the items.
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}", item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Casper. DynamicQueryable throws out System.Linq.Lookup<DynamicClass, Employee>.Grouping.

Comment: @idea what is it that you're looking for beyond that?

Comment: I am unable to work with the Key represented by DynamicClass since its a runtime type created by DynamicQueryable. May be there is a way to work with it, but the work around I found is explicitly project the Key in the dynamic selectors alongwith the Employee list. Thanks for pitching in.