# How to use GroupBy using Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I am trying to do a GroupBy using Dynamic LINQ but have trouble getting it to work.

This is some sample code illustrating the problem:

```
List<dtoMyAlbum> listAlbums = new List<dtoMyAlbum>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
    dtoMyAlbum album = new dtoMyAlbum
    {
        Author = "My Author",
        BookID = i,
        CurrSymbol = "USD",
        Price = 23.23,
        Shop = i % 3 == 0 ? "TESCO" : "HMV"
    };
    listAlbums.Add(album);
}

IQueryable<dtoMyAlbum> mydata = listAlbums.AsQueryable();
int count = mydata.Count();

//var mydataGrouped = mydata.GroupBy(a => a.Shop);      // <-- this works well (but is not dynamic....)
var mydataGrouped = mydata.GroupBy("Shop");             // <-- does not compile but is kind of what I want...

foreach (var group in mydataGrouped)
{
    //count = group.Count();
}
```

I realise that I am missing the 'elementSelector' in the GroupBy overload but all I want to do is to end up with (in this case) two sets of dtoMyAlbum objects so I wish to select ALL elements for all sets...

How would I go about this?

Comment: Don't you just mean `mydata.Where(x => x.Shop == "HMV");`?

Comment: No, I am trying to GroupBy - not a Where clause.  And bear in mind I am trying to achieve this with dynamic sql NOT standard lambda!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is default `it` defined, you can use it to return matched elements:

```
var mydataGrouped = mydata.GroupBy("Shop", "it");
```

To iterate through results you should additionally `Select` elements to name it and use `dynamic`s:

```
var mydataGrouped = mydata.GroupBy("Shop", "it").Select("new (it.Key as Shop, it as Albums)");

foreach (dynamic group in mydataGrouped)
{
   foreach (dynamic album in group.Albums)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(album.Author);
   }
}
```

Comment: That is brilliant and seems to work but how would I iterate over the resulting groups?

Comment: just use ToList(); and If you have a new type than you have to select them new {shop... etc.}

Comment: Not sure I understand - the groups are of type IGrouping - there is nowhere an option to do a ToList...

Comment: That works well thanks, but seems pretty inefficient since I have to create new List<T>'s out of the result in order to pass them on.  Is there another way (like ToList<>)?

Comment: got pointed by someone to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396813/dynamic-linq-groupby-select-key-listt

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may construct the group by expression dynamically or give a try to this Dynamic LINQ library presented on ScottGu's page:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I have copied from DynamicQuery:

```
public static IQueryable GroupBy(this IQueryable source, string keySelector, string elementSelector, params object[] values) {..}
```

In my example I provide the ***keySelector*** and the ***elementSelector***.

`listAlbums.AsQueryable().GroupBy("it.Shop", "it").Select("Author");  You can use new with` GroupBy or with select for the new types.

***It*** like **this** in OOP **class.**