# Dynamic Linq select first in groups after GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I think I've read every post on this subject but still can't seem to get this to work.
I want to duplicate the following GroupBy with dynamic Linq. I've tried this [Dynamic GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329558/how-to-use-groupby-using-dynamic-linq) but can't seem to get the First().

```
var result = mydata
    .GroupBy(g => g.ID)
    .Select(z => z.First())
    .Select("new (ID, Field1, Field2)");
```

The GroupBy needs to be dynamic. I need the first row of the grouped field.
So..

```
ID:1, Field1:W, Field2:L 
ID:1, Field1:A, Field2:B 
ID:2, Field1:A, Field2:B 
ID:2, Field1:C, Field2:D
```

Should end up being:

```
ID:1, Field1:W, Field2:L 
ID:2, Field1:A, Field2:B 
OR
ID:1, Field1:A, Field2:B 
ID:2, Field1:C, Field2:D
```

Comment: Yes lol..I need the GroupBy part to be dynamic so I can use a string instead of strong typing "ID".

Comment: btw, I tried the link you provided. But can not get it to yield the result created by the query I said I need to duplicate.

Comment: Yes the problem is getting the First()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by adding to DynamicQueryable

```
public static object First(this IQueryable source)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
            return source.Provider.Execute(
                Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable), "First",
                    new Type[] { source.ElementType },
                    source.Expression));
        }
```

Above not required..but added anyway for consistency.

And adding to `IEnumerableSignatures`

```
void First()
```

Query becomes:

```
var result = mydata
    .GroupBy("ID", "it")
    .Select("it.First()")
    .Select("new (ID, Field1, Field2)");
```

Answer (score -2):

What about this

```
            var mydata = new[] {
                new { ID = 1, Field1 = "W", Field2 = "L"},
                new { ID = 1, Field1 = "A", Field2 = "B"}, 
                new { ID = 2, Field1 = "A", Field2 = "B"}, 
                new { ID = 2, Field1 = "C", Field2 = "D"}
            }.ToList();


            var result = mydata.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
                .Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();​

            var output = result[0][0];

            var output1 = result[0];
            var output2 = result[1];
```

Comment: This question is specifically about [tag:dynamic-linq], which allows to [build string based query expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dynamic-linq/info), not about standard expression(delegate)-based LINQ.

Comment: I created sample data for testing.   Should work on dynamic expressions.

Comment: This code is not dynamic-linq. Dynamic LINQ deals with strings. Not with expressions or delegates.

Comment: I disagree.  Using ToList() makes it a dynamic expression.  I think the real issue is using ToList() in the GroupBy is the solution,  Then var output = result.FirstOrDefault() gives correct results.

Comment: You can take a look at [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30540462/3745022) that really uses [tag:dynamic-linq]. Have you read the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dynamic-linq/info)? No offense, but what you propose does not use the technology required by OP.