# How can I let users specify which entity properties are used in a Linq-to-Objects GroupBy query expression at runtime?

Tags: c#, linq

Backstory:

So I have a little demo application I'm working on which is looking through songs and trying to find duplicates based on tags the user specifies. Initially I was just using the below query which I'm trying to generalize.

```
var query = MusicFiles.GroupBy(x => 
        new { x?.Tag.FirstArtist, x?.Tag.Title }
    ).Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .ToList();
```

Now though I want to have the user specify these properties so I used reflection to get all properties of the `TagLib.Tag` class and now allow the user to specify the tags they are interested in.

Question:

How can I use this new list of strings representing the properties of the class and group by **all of these** properties alternatively how can I generalize the above line of code.

My initial train of thought and what I've tried has been to try and create an anonymous object like above and use reflection to get each property, but since I'm iterating over a list of string properties I end up with an anonymous object for each property rather than an anonymous object of all properties selected

Answer (score 0):

I just built something like this for a pivot table style report, that I can't share with you right now. My recommendation would be to start with a template group by expression that contains all of the possible grouping fields. Then create an `ExpressionVisitor` to find the `MemberInitExpression`, and remove any `MemberBinding` that the user **hasn't** selected. This way, you still have a strongly typed group by expression, that can use any feature of EF Core without needing to reimplement it.

```cs
Expression<Func<X,TagGroup>> template = x => 
        new TagGroup { x?.Tag.FirstArtist, x?.Tag.Title, ... };

public Filter : ExpressionVisitor{
    public Filter(... selection){ ... }
    protected override Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node){
        return node.Update(node.NewExpression, node.Bindings.Where( ... ));
    }
}

var groupBy = new Filter(selection).Visit(template);
```

Filling in the blanks left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Dynamic-Linq` library which provides Linq extension-methods that accept string arguments to specify object members instead of `Func<...>` and `Expression<Func<...>>`, then follow the advice in this QA: [How to use GroupBy using Dynamic LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329558/how-to-use-groupby-using-dynamic-linq)

It's available on NuGet via a third-party "maintained" version of Microsoft's original official `System.Linq.Dynamic.dll` assembly as `Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` or `Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic` and mirrored on GitHub here: https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions (an older version is available here: https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic )

In the more recent version for .NET Standard, the extension method you want is [`GroupBy( this IQueryable source, String keySelector, params Object\[\] args )`](https://stefh.github.io/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/html/82cab2b4-8a2a-f0b1-0b02-004e75f7e79f.htm).

Then your query would become:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

[...]

IReadOnlyList<String> userSelectedPropertyList = ...
// e.g. userSelectedPropertyList = new[] { "FirstArtist", "Title" };

String dynamicLinqGroupByKeySelector = "new (" + String.Join( ", ", userSelectedPropertyList ) + ")";
// so the GroupBy keySelector looks like "new (FirstArtist, Title)".

var query = MusicFiles
    .GroupBy( dynamicLinqGroupByKeySelector )
    .Where( g => g.Count() > 1 )
    .ToList();
```